# Create New Parent Site for Subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy, sub-site

I have a two level site at the moment

1. A corporate site
2. A project site.

I'd like to put a new site that we have created in our office to manage the projects corporately.

I'd like it to break down `Corporate > Project Management > Projects (multiple)` but I'm not sure how to put a site in the middle of the current relationship.

How do I add a subsite to the Corporate site that will be a site above the Project site?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it uisng the Content and Structure feature of SharePoint. But this feature required SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and SharePoint Server Publishing.

1. Create a new Subsite
2. Go to Site and Content Structure
3. Move the subsite to under different subsite or whatever you want.

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/178692